# positive definite operator and unique solution

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the page 32/39 of this paper http://archive.numdam.org/article/M2AN_1981__15_1_41_0.pdf they have the following equation:

$T_h u_{h,t}+u_h=T_h f$

and say: "Since $T_h$ is definite positive (...) this problem admits a unique solution $u_h(t)$" ( the lemma 3.7 establishes that $T_h$ is definite positive)

I don't understand the argument, because i put $L:=\dfrac{d}{dt}+T_h^{-1}$ and the equation above may be written as

$L(u_h)=f$ and this have unique solution iff $L$ is definite positive, but

$(u_h,L(u_h))=(u_h,u_{h,t})+(u_h,T_h^{-1}u_h)$

I get that $(u_h,T_h^{-1}u_h)>0$ because $T_h$ is definite positive, but $(u_h,u_{h,t})=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt}||u_h(t)||^2$ is not necessarily greater than $0$, the condition must we have that $||u_h(t)||^2$ is increasing with $t$ but this isn't true necessarily.

Can anyone help me?